# Running an Adobe Acrobat action from Command Line (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, pdf, acrobat

I'm trying to convert some PDF files to PDF/X-1A format. I've created an action in Acrobat to do this, and I would like to call this from NodeJS whenever a new PDF file is created with my current process. Then I want to serve the converted file back to the user. There doesn't seem to be any other solutions out there to convert/compress PDFs in the way that Acrobat Pro does, so this is why I am pursuing this option.

My process is basically as follows:

```
genPdf:function(content,cb){
    // Config for PDF generation, etc
    // ...

    pdfGenerator.doConversion(config, pdfPath, function(result) {
        // After file is generated, I want to call my adobe action
        var cmd = 'call_adobe_acrobat_action_cmd';

        exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
          // After action is called I'll initiate a watch on the directory that the action will write the converted file to
          // When conversion has completed, I will serve the converted file back to the user
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's actually a violation of the Acrobat license agreement to use it in that fashion. Acrobat Actions can process multiple files but the Action needs to be triggered by a user.

Check out pdfToolbox Server for server-side automated conversion from PDF to PDF/X.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the heads up. Unfortunately pdfToolbox is out of my project's budget so I will have to look for a different solution.

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to achieve by converting to PDF/X-1A? The purpose of PDF/X is for graphics exchange, and has a series of printing related requirements that don't apply to standard PDF files. You only mention compression. If you don't really need a PDF/X file as your output, you may be able to get the compression you want using PDFBox, which is free, it's Java but you can easily call it from Node.

Comment: We have two sets of files, one of which is to be used for high resolution printing with CMYK images and FOGRA39 ICC. Unfortunately because of this, conversion to PDF/X-1A is necessary as it is a requirement by the printing company. I've been using GhostScript for compressing the standard resolution PDFs and it has been sufficient, but it doesn't appear to handle PDF/X-1A conversion.

Comment: Ok - So you really do need PDF/X. I'm sure this isn't what you want to hear but I strongly suggest you *find* the budget for pdfToolbox Server. There are cheaper tools out there but they tend to shift color and fail at processing most of the blending modes in PDF. Callas licenses the Adobe PDF Library which also has the Adobe Color Engine in it, the same library and color engine as Adobe uses in Acrobat. Callas also supplies Adobe with the tech  in Acrobat's preflight tool. That's really the only way you'll get color to be consistent between the Adobe viewers and your PDF/X files.

Answer (score 2):

The Acrobat plugin [AutoBatch](https://www.evermap.com/autobatch.asp) will allow you to create a `.bat` file which will launch Acrobat and run a given "action" you have defined in Acrobat.

Note that AutoBatch is not free.

The batch files created by AutoBatch actually just set some environment variables, which are presumably picked up by the Acrobat plugin, which in turn triggers your action.

Example `.bat` file produced by AutoBatch:

```
SET AUTOBATCHSEQU=C:\Users\IEUser\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Acrobat\10.0\Sequences\myaction.sequ
SET AUTOBATCHFINAL=0
SET AUTOBATCHDEST=
SET AUTOBATCHALTPATH=%1
SET AUTOBATCHALTOUTPUTPATH=%2
SET AUTOBATCHNOPROGRESS=no
SET AUTOBATCHFILEEXT=
SET AUTOBATCHNOSUBFOLDERS=no
"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat 10.0\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe" /n /h
```